# Command to count characters in a specified string

Tags: macros, strings

Is there a way to count the number of characters in a specified string?

Suppose I had the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\numchars}[1]{\noindent The string ``#1" has ? characters.\\}
\begin{document}
\numchars{everything}
\numchars{that's not it!}
\numchars{weird}
\end{document}
```

How would I make it display the correct character count like this

[image: character count]

without having to do a manual count?

Comment: Is a LuaTeX solution acceptable?

Comment: @Pouya, I'm not familiar with LuaTeX, so I'd prefer just plain LaTeX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your argument contains macros, the answer would need to change.  Spaces count as characters, though that could be adjusted if you desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand{\numchars}[1]{\noindent The string ``#1'' has \stringlength{#1} characters.\\}
\begin{document}
\numchars{everything}
\numchars{that's not it!}
\numchars{weird}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version that does not count spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand{\numchars}[1]{%
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{ }{}%
  \noindent The string ``#1'' has \stringlength{\thestring} characters.\\
}
\begin{document}
\numchars{everything}
\numchars{that's not it!}
\numchars{weird}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you wanted to count only alphabetic characters (ignoring numbers, spaces and punctuation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand{\numchars}[1]{%
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{ }{}%
  \alphabetic[q]{\thestring}%
  \noindent The string ``#1'' has \stringlength{\thestring} characters.\\
}
\begin{document}
\numchars{everything}
\numchars{that's not it!}
\numchars{weird}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\StrLen` from `xstring` is also an option. Although, I'm not sure which one is the better...

Comment: @Pouya It is likely that the `xstring` answer is better, but since I wrote `stringstrings`, I go with what I know.

Comment: @pouya, I tried \StrLen from xstring and it also worked. Thanks.

Comment: The "basic" version of the `\numchars` macro, i.e., the one that returns `14` for "that's not it!", returns `5` rather than `3` when run on the UTF8-encoded string "öüß", if run under pdfLaTeX and with the `inputenc` package loaded with the option `utf8`. Oddly, `6` is returned if the `inputenc` package is *not* loaded. And, interestingly, it returns `3` when run under LuaLaTeX (and `fontspec`  is loaded).

Comment: @Mico Absolutely true that there is no support for Unicode with this solution.

Comment: I wouldn't put it that negatively. There is *full support* for Unicode-encoded (more precisely, utf8-encoded) characters *if* the document is compiled with LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the OP has stated that he/she isn't interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution, others may still value having such a solution. :-)

The following solution works with strings of UTF8-encoded characters. Because ASCII-encoded characters are automatically UTF8-encoded, the solution also works with ASCII-encoded strings.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luastring" macro
\newcommand{\numchars}[1]{\noindent The string ``#1'' has 
    \directlua{tex.sprint(unicode.utf8.len(\luastring{#1}))} 
    characters.\par}

\begin{document}
\numchars{everything}
\numchars{öüß}
\end{document}
```

*Aside*: If the Lua-side code inappropriately used the function `string.len` instead of `unicode.utf8.len`, the macro `\numchars` would report that `öüß` has 6 characters. This happens because each of the 3 characters in `öüß` is encoded using 2 bytes in the utf8 system. (The function `str.len` does a byte count rather than a direct character account; that's OK if each character is encoded using exactly 1 byte, which is the case for the ASCII encoding system, though not for most others.) Likewise, the string `ø§¶®€œ¥√Ç±` would incorrectly be diagnosed as having 22 [!] rather than just 10 characters, as both `€` and `√` are encoded using 3 bytes and the remaining 8 characters are encoded using 2 bytes each. Clearly, it's important to use the function `unicode.utf8.len` in the present context.

Comment: You might want to add that this also works with the long Lorem string.

Answer (score 2):

The command `\newcommand{\numchars}[1]`... works well, but I encountered some issues with `\stringlength` in the `stringstrings`package. It seems like it has a limit of 500 on the number of characters, returning zero if you go above that. For example, the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand{\numchars}[1]{\noindent The string ``#1'' has \stringlength{#1} characters.\\}

\begin{document}
\numchars{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tris- tique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pul- vinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.}
\end{document}
```

Returns:

[image]

The command `\StrLen` in the `xstring` package seems to work better. The document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\numchars}[1]{\noindent The string ``#1'' has {\StrLen{#1}} characters.\\}

\begin{document}
\numchars{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tris- tique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pul- vinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.}
\end{document}
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you expand your answer with an example of how to use `\StrLen`? As it is now, it's more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If I run your `\numchars` macro under pdfLaTeX on the UTF8-encoded string "öüß", I get `5` (rather than `3`) if the `inputenc` package is loaded with the option `utf8`, and I get `6` if the `inputenc` package isn't loaded. (Interestingly, I get `3` -- the correct number! -- if I run your `\numchars` macro under LuaLaTeX/fontspec.) Is there a way to fix up your macro so that it runs correctly under pdfLaTeX for UTF8-encoded strings?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably there's an excellent reason not to use l3 syntax because egreg has not written an answer.

Also note: ***I do not know what I'm doing.***

---

## *Caveat emptor...*

The `expl3` package is used to enable l3 syntax. (The LaTeX equivalent of the latest thing since sliced bread.) `xparse` is used to easily define a starred form of the command which excludes spaces from the character count.

Because l3 is oblivious to spaces by default, the extra work actually goes into the non-starred form of the command which converts all spaces to `x`s before doing the count.

Note that this solution will count accented characters as decomposed with pdfTeX. With Xe/LuaTeX, it works provided a font supporting the characters is used. Thanks to comments for discussion.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn  % enable l3 syntax
\tl_new:N \l_qzx_string_tl  % declare a local token list to hold qzx's string
\NewDocumentCommand \numchars { s m }{  % command optionally takes a star and requires a single argument
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_qzx_string_tl { #2 }  % set the token list to the string we've been fed
  \IfBooleanF { #1 }  % if there is no star
    {  % then replace all instances of a space (~ in l3 syntax) by instances of x
      \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_qzx_string_tl { ~ } { x }
    }
  % the count of the characters in the token list goes straight into the stream to be typeset but we need to add the spaces we want here explicitly using ~
  \noindent The~string~``#2"~has~\tl_count:N \l_qzx_string_tl{}~characters.\par  % use \par rather than \\ to avoid complaints about bad boxes
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff% turn l3 syntax off so everything is back to normal and giraffes are giraffes once more
```

[image: count strings 2 ways]

### Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_qzx_string_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \numchars { s m }{
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_qzx_string_tl { #2 }
  \IfBooleanF { #1 }
    {
      \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_qzx_string_tl { ~ } { x }
    }
  \noindent The~string~``#2"~has~\tl_count:N \l_qzx_string_tl{}~characters.\par
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \numchars{everything}
  \numchars*{everything}
  \numchars{that's not it!}
  \numchars*{that's not it!}
  \numchars{weird}
  \numchars*{weird}
  \numchars{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.}
  \numchars*{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.}
\end{document}
```

---

*This will certainly break if fed wonderful things before breakfast, is likely to feel a little fragile prior to lunch and will probably need to spend the afternoon recovering before getting an early night.*

As I said, *caveat emptor...*.

Comment: Your code, when run on the UTF8-encoded string "öüß", returns 6 rather than 3 as the character count. Is there a way to adjust the macro so that it counts characters rather than bytes in the string?

Comment: @Mico It does count 6 if one uses pdfTeX, if you use LuaTeX or XeTeX it does count three. Not the perfect solution, I know.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, but with Xe/LuaTeX the count is right by the content of the string disappears and you end up with `The string “” has 3 characters.` which is not good (and makes the statement false even though the count was originally right).

Comment: @Mico I don't know. I'm very new to this syntax. Perhaps this is why egreg didn't answer?

Comment: @Mico For now, I've just explained the limitation....

Comment: @cfr That only has to do with the font used, if you load `fontspec` in Xe-LuaTeX it all goes well. But, as I've shown in my answer (not complete, though), it can also be done in pdfTeX.

Comment: @Manuel 'Characters' is poorly defined in the question: for example, what about `foo{bar}` (assuming normal catcodes). I think provided the details are clear any reasonable outcome is OK. (To count `öüß` with pdfTeX you'd need to convert to LICR, for example.)

Comment: @cfr - Just as an aside: To get your code to print `The string “öüß” has (x) characters` rather than `The string “” has 3 characters`, it suffices to load the `inputenc` package with the option `utf8` and the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`.

Comment: @Mico  I get `6` in that case. (The string is printed  correctly but the count is wrong.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant write 6, not 3. Your code, at least, gives the "correct incorrect" result of 6 when run on "öüß" under pdfLaTeX. In contrast, the code in the answers of Steven and Cão returns 5 (when run under pdfLaTeX and the `inputenc` package is loaded with the option `utf8`). I can understand where `6` comes from (viz, counting the bytes used to encode the characters), but I have no idea where the `5` result may come from.

Comment: @Mico Oh, I see. Yes, it does. The `6` made sense to me. Not sure what to say about `5` so I'm glad my code didn't produce it else I'd have to worry about it!

Answer (score 2):

The problem Mico points out can be solved in @cfr's solution just by using LuaTeX or XeTeX. If one is bounded to pdfTeX engine, a possible solution is to use the amazingly powerful `l3regex` package.

*Edit:* As egreg pointed out, I didn't know that there were so many multibyte prefixes.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \numchars { s m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \IfBooleanF { #1 } { \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { x } }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { [\x{C2}-\x{DF}].   } { x } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { [\x{E0}-\x{EF}]..  } { x } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { [\x{F0}-\x{F4}]... } { x } \l_tmpa_tl

  The ~ string ~ ``#2'' ~ has ~ \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl \space characters
  \IfBooleanT { #1 } { ~ (ignoring ~ whitespace)} .\par
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \numchars{ßöü—} % em-dash
  \numchars{everything}
  \numchars*{everything}
  \numchars{that's not it!}
  \numchars*{that's not it!}
  \numchars{weird}
  \numchars*{weird}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

The string “ßöü—” has 4 characters.
The string “everything” has 10 characters.
The string “everything” has 10 characters (ignoring whitespace).
The string “that’s not it!” has 14 characters.
The string “that’s not it!” has 12 characters (ignoring whitespace).
The string “weird” has 5 characters.
The string “weird” has 5 characters (ignoring whitespace).

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the active characters of multibyte unicode right: `^^c3`, `^^e2`, `^^f0`?

Comment: There are many more. Two byte prefixes are from C2 to DF; three byte prefixes from E0 to EF; four byte from F0 to F4.

Comment: Okey, I definitely did not get them right :) Any suggestion as of how to make it easier? Rather than having around 30 lines of code? By the way, where do you learn that? I googled and found nothing.

Comment: Perhaps force conversion to LICR first (`\protected@edef` then some work to cut the result down to the essentials).

Comment: @JosephWright You better add that answer, I don't know what LICR is :)

Comment: Not very efficient, but you can do `\regex_const:Nn \c_utf_two_byte_prefix_regex { (\x{C2}|\x{C3}|\x{C4}|<etc>) . }` and similarly for the other prefixes and use `\regex_replace_all:NnN \c_utf_two_byte_prefix_regex { x }`

Comment: @egreg Is that faster than just many many `\regex_replace_all:nnN`?

Comment: I did no benchmarking. I didn't try at all, TBH.

Comment: @egreg Much easier: `\regex_replace_all:nnN { [\x{C2}-\x{DF}].   } { x } \l_tmpa_tl`. Yeah, efficiency won't be the best here :)

Answer (score 0):

What about the following solution?

```
 \def\numchars #1{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\tt#1}
   \setbox1=\hbox{\tt 1}
   \count100 = \wd0
   \count101 = \wd1
   \divide\count100 by \count101
   The string "#1" has \the\count100\ characters.
}
```

\numchars{This is the character"a!}

will produce
The string "This is the characterä!" has 23 characters.

The macro will work if the characters are in or produced from the charaters in the
used font (for example cmr10).