# how to determine the number of characters in the argument of a command

Tags: macros, arguments

I want to define a command that behaves differently for single-character arguments than it does for longer arguments. How do I retrieve the number of characters in, e.g., `#1`?

The specific application that I have in mind is to set variable names in italic if they are single letters and otherwise to set them in Roman. Something like

```
\newcommand \mathvar [1] {
    \ifthenelse {\characters{#1} = 1}
    {\mathit{#1))
    {\mathrm{#1}}     
}
```

And, yes, I really mean the number of nonblank characters, not the size of the rendered text.

Note that I want to be able to submit to arXiv.org, and they do not support, e.g., LuaTeX, XeTeX. I'm currently using PDFlatex via MIKTeX, and don't know whether e-TeX is acceptable to arXiv; their current build is rather old.

I tried using xstring; since it doesn't support #, I had to resort to a hack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand {\funcname} [1]
   {
     \edef\Parameter1{#1}
     \StrDel[0]{\Parameter1}{ }[\stripped]
     \ifthenelse {\StrLen{\stripped} > 1}
       {\mathrm{#1}}
       {#1}
   }

\begin{document}

Test StrDel \{ foo \} \{ \} = /\StrDel { foo } { }/

\edef\Parameter1{ foo }
\StrDel {\Parameter1} { }[\stripped]
Test StrLen StrDel \{ foo \} \{ \} = \StrLen{\stripped}

Test funcname T funcname Table = $\funcname{T} \funcname{Table}$

\end{document}
```

and that gave me

```
! Argument of \@xs@StrDel has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.25 ...funcname T funcname Table = $\funcname{T}
                                                   \funcname{Table}$
```

Comment: Do you really need the number of characters, or would the width of them be sufficient?

Comment: Number of characters: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230911/36296

Comment: Maybe you could add a simple example of what you need.

Comment: Please always post complete minimal code we can compile as it makes it much easier for people to help. Especially if it isn't entirely clear what you are asking, complete code can really simplify things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easy with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mathvar}{m}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:n { #1 } > 1 }
   {
    \mathrm{#1}
   }
   {
    #1 % or \mathit{#1}, but I wouldn't do it
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mathvar{V}\ne\mathvar{Var}$

\end{document}
```

The code should be self-explaining: `\tl_count:n` counts the number of items in its argument (ignoring spaces, however).

I wouldn't use `\mathit` for single letter variables, as normal math italic is specially tailored for the purpose.

[image]

An implementation with `xstring`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mathvar}[1]{%
  \begingroup\noexpandarg
  \StrLen{#1}[\temp]%
  \ifnum\temp>1
    \mathrm{#1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$\mathvar{V}\ne\mathvar{Var}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitely self-`expl`aining :P

Comment: Do you know if arxiv.org accepts LaTeX3-based code? (The OP has edited his posting to note that he intends to submit his paper to arxiv.org.)

Comment: @Mico I hope so

Comment: Perfect if arXiv will accept manuscripts requiring xparse. They are already requiring that I include tikz-cd and pgf in my source file if I want to use them, so I wonder if I'll also need to include expl3 and xparse.\\I'd still like to know what's wong with my xstring code.

Comment: @shmuel For instance, you can do `\edef\Parameter1{...}`, but you should be aware that this defines the macro `\Parameter` and `\Parameter1` cannot be used in `\StrDel`. By the way, including `tikz-cd` and PGF in your submission is something I would be scared about.

Comment: @shmuel I added a simple implementation with `xstring`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a macro called `\numchars`, which returns the number of characters in its argument, and an implementation of `\mathvar`. Care is taken not to count whitespace characters in the argument of `\mathvar`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{luacode} %  for "\luastring" macro and "luacode" environment
\begin{luacode}
function numchars ( s )  -- disregard any whitespace characters
   return tex.sprint ( unicode.utf8.len ( unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "%s", "")))
end 
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\numchars[1]{\directlua{numchars(\luastring{#1})}}
\newcommand\mathvar[1]{%
   \ifnum\numchars{#1}<2\mathit{#1}\else\mathrm{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}
$\mathvar{ V }$, $\mathvar{VaR}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: I posted this answer *before* the OP edited his posting and provided a caveat that only pdfLaTeX-based answers would be useful to him (as he's planning to use the code in a document that's to be submitted to arxiv.org).

Answer (score 5):

Plainer solution.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\long\def\gobbleone#1{}
\newcommand*\var[1]{\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbleone#1}\relax#1\else\mathrm{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}

$\var{A} = \var{B} = \var{Whatever}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code returns the incorrect answer if there is whitespace in the argument of `\var`.  E.g., `\var{A }` (note the space after "A") will generate an upright "A" instead of an italic "A". Can you modify the code to disregard whitespace in the argument of `\var`?

Comment: @Mico It also does return an error if the argument is empty (or blank) `\var{}`, but I don't think it's necessary unless the OP asks for it.

Comment: The OP did specify "the number of nonblank characters", so it seems likely that his document may feature whitespace characters in the argument of `mathvar` (or `\var`) directives.