# How can I change a sentence based upon input to a command?

Tags: luatex, protein

I am writing a report that includes enzyme images such as this:

[image]

In the `\caption` I would like to include a colour guide so that key components/atoms can be described in colour (this report is not being published so with respect to colour blindness this is not an issue). I am currently using a command like this:

```
\newcommand\ColourGuide{%
Colour code: \textcolor{violet}{metal ion}, \textcolor{Green3}{residue}, \textcolor{teal}{ligand}, \textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate}, \textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus}, \textcolor{red}{oxygen} and \textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen}%
}
```

However, with some images not all of the coloured components are present so it would not be good to include redundant colour codes. How can I create a sentence based upon input? For example:

`\ColourGuide{M}{R}{S}{O}{N}`

would produce:

> Colour code: metal ion, residue, substrate, oxygen and nitrogen.

in the colours specified. I am using `lualatex` and looked at using `lua` (which would be nice) but I do not know how to interact the two properly (nor efficiently), how could the arguments be extracted for example like in Python with `input[0]`? I would appreciate any advice or solutions via any method but `lua` would be nice so I can start learning it and applying it to other commands, I use `lualatex` frequently.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\newcommand\ColourGuide{%
Colour code: \textcolor{violet}{metal ion}, \textcolor{Green3}{residue}, \textcolor{teal}{ligand}, \textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate}, \textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus}, \textcolor{red}{oxygen} and \textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen}%
}

\begin{document}

\ColourGuide{}

\end{document}
```

How it looks:

[image]

(I am not sure what tags to put on this)

Comment: I would use a comma list as argument, and you can various example how to process that here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think I have ever used a comma list before, I didn't know that, thanks for the advice. Do you mean like the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139176/how-do-i-process-a-comma-separated-list-passed-through-a-command#139188

Comment: You can use xstring to parse the commas, or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C39.4796  You can also use `\ColourGuide{MRSON}` and pull off the letters one at a time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo is there a way to get the total tokens values (as in 3 or 5) so that commas can be used and the final one can be separated with `and #1.`. I would appreciate if there is an existing answer like that I cannot find one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good attempt in your answer, but…

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ColourGuide}{m}
 {
  Color~code:~\jamest_colourguide:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__jamest_colourguide_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jamest_colourguide:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__jamest_colourguide_seq
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__jamest_colourguide_add:n
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__jamest_colourguide_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jamest_colourguide_add:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__jamest_colourguide_seq
   {
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
     {
      {a}{\textcolor{red}{oxygen},~\textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus},~
          \textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate},~\textcolor{Green3}{residue},~
          \textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen},~\textcolor{teal}{ligand}~
          and~\textcolor{violet}{metal~ion}.}
      {M}{\textcolor{violet}{metal~ion}}
      {R}{\textcolor{Green3}{residue}}
      {S}{\textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate}}
      {O}{\textcolor{red}{oxygen}}
      {N}{\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen}}
      {L}{\textcolor{teal}{ligand}}
      {P}{\textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus}}
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent\ColourGuide{MRSON}

\noindent\ColourGuide{LPON}

\noindent\ColourGuide{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

No counting is needed: the argument is mapped character by character and the relevant code is added to the sequence that can later be used with the suitable separators.

Perhaps better, so to avoid code duplication, is to leave the argument empty if you want the full list.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ColourGuide}{m}
 {
  Color~code:~
  \jamest_colourguide:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__jamest_colourguide_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jamest_colourguide:n
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \jamest_colourguide:n { OPSRNLM }
   }
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l__jamest_colourguide_seq
    \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__jamest_colourguide_add:n
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__jamest_colourguide_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jamest_colourguide_add:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__jamest_colourguide_seq
   {
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
     {
      {M}{\textcolor{violet}{metal~ion}}
      {R}{\textcolor{Green3}{residue}}
      {S}{\textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate}}
      {O}{\textcolor{red}{oxygen}}
      {N}{\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen}}
      {L}{\textcolor{teal}{ligand}}
      {P}{\textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus}}
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent\ColourGuide{MRSON}

\noindent\ColourGuide{LPON}

\noindent\ColourGuide{}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to piece together a solution that is not pretty but works as required. Adding an answer by @egreg to [how to determine the number of characters in the argument of a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326507/273733) and the linked answer @John Kormylo [commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233227/273733) gives this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcounter{Chars}
\newcounter{CharsConstant}

\def\CharsCount#1{%
    \setcounter{Chars}{\tl_count:n { #1 }}%
    \setcounter{CharsConstant}{\tl_count:n { #1 }}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\punctOrAnd}{mm}
    {
    \int_compare:nTF { #1 > 1 }
    {
    \int_compare:nTF { #1 = \value{CharsConstant} }
        {
            #2
            }
            {
            ,~#2
            }
    }
    {
    \space and~#2.
    }
 }

\def\ColourGuide#1{\CharsCount{#1}Colour~code:~\scanA#1\end}
\def\scanA#1{%
    \ifx\end#1\else
        \IfStrEq{#1}{a}{\textcolor{red}{oxygen},~\textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus},~\textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate},~\textcolor{Green3}{residue},~\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen},~\textcolor{teal}{ligand}~and~\textcolor{violet}{metal~ion}.}{}%
        %
        \IfStrEq{#1}{M}{\punctOrAnd{\value{Chars}}{\textcolor{violet}{metal~ion}}}{}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{R}{\punctOrAnd{\value{Chars}}{\textcolor{Green3}{residue}}}{}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{S}{\punctOrAnd{\value{Chars}}{\textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate}}}{}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{O}{\punctOrAnd{\value{Chars}}{\textcolor{red}{oxygen}}}{}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{N}{\punctOrAnd{\value{Chars}}{\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen}}}{}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{L}{\punctOrAnd{\value{Chars}}{\textcolor{teal}{ligand}}}{}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{P}{\punctOrAnd{\value{Chars}}{\textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus}}}{}%
        %
        \addtocounter{Chars}{-1}%
    \expandafter \scanA \fi
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent\ColourGuide{MRSON}

\noindent\ColourGuide{LPON}

\noindent\ColourGuide{a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a more efficient version without code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

This uses a semicolon as a terminator.  `\def\CGparse#1#2;` will put the first token (letter) in `#1` and everything before the semicolon in `#2`.  It calls itself recursively until `#2` is `\empty`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\newcommand\ColourGuide[1]{Colour code:{\count1=0\relax\CGparse#1;}}

\def\CGparse#1#2;{\def\A{#1}%
  \def\B{#2}%
  \ifnum\count1=0\relax
    \space
  \else
    \ifx\B\empty\relax
      { and }%
    \else
      {, }%
    \fi
  \fi
  \advance\count1 by 1
  \def\C{M}\ifx\A\C\relax\textcolor{violet}{metal ion}\fi
  \def\C{R}\ifx\A\C\relax\textcolor{Green3}{residue}\fi
  \def\C{L}\ifx\A\C\relax\textcolor{teal}{ligand}\fi
  \def\C{S}\ifx\A\C\relax\textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate}\fi
  \def\C{P}\ifx\A\C\relax\textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus}\fi
  \def\C{O}\ifx\A\C\relax\textcolor{red}{oxygen}\fi
  \def\C{N}\ifx\A\C\relax\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen}\fi
  \ifx\B\empty\relax
    {.  }%
  \else 
    \CGparse#2;
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\ColourGuide{MRSON}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already many good answers, and probably mine using `pgfkeys` is far too complicated and cumbersome, but this is what I came up with.

- No need for `lualatex` (which was requested explicitly here, but maybe someone can use this somewhere else).
- The atoms will always be listed in the same order, no matter whether you write `\ColourGuide[ligand,residue]` or `\ColourGuide[residue,ligand]`. This can be wanted or not, but I think it is good style to keep the same order.

Of course the optional arguments/keys could be shortened to e.g. `\ColourGuide[L,R]` with almost no effort.

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}

% create 'if's for each atom
\newif\ifmetalion
\newif\ifresidue
\newif\ifligand
\newif\ifsubstrate
\newif\ifphosphorus
\newif\ifoxygen
\newif\ifnitrogen

% create two counters
\newcounter{numtrue} % total number of 'if's which are true
\newcounter{currval} % counter (for correctly putting 'and' at the last atom)

% colors
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

% create pgfkeys
\usepackage{pgfkeys,xcolor}
\pgfkeys{
    /colourguide/.is family, /colourguide/.cd,
    default/.style={
        metalion=false,
        residue=false,
        ligand=false,
        substrate=false,
        phosphorus=false,
        oxygen=false,
        nitrogen=false,
    },
    metalion/.is if=metalion,
    residue/.is if=residue,
    ligand/.is if=ligand,
    substrate/.is if=substrate,
    phosphorus/.is if=phosphorus,
    oxygen/.is if=oxygen,
    nitrogen/.is if=nitrogen
}

% this will produce the adequate delimiter between different atoms
\def\chooseDelimiter{%
    \stepcounter{currval}% increment counter
    \ifnum\value{currval}<\value{numtrue}\relax%     if more than one atom remains ...
        ,\ %                                         ... put ',' ...
    \else%                                           
        \ifnum\value{currval}=\value{numtrue}\relax% ... if only one atom remains ...
            \ and\ %                                 ... put 'and' ...
        \else%                                       ... if no atom remains ...
            .%                                       ... put '.'
        \fi%
    \fi%
}

% main command: \ColorGuide
\newcommand\ColourGuide[1][]{%
    % do pgfkeys magic
    \pgfkeys{/colourguide, default, #1}%
    % get number of requested atoms
    \setcounter{currval}{1}%
    \setcounter{numtrue}{0}%
    \ifmetalion  \stepcounter{numtrue}\fi%
    \ifresidue   \stepcounter{numtrue}\fi%
    \ifligand    \stepcounter{numtrue}\fi%
    \ifsubstrate \stepcounter{numtrue}\fi%
    \ifphosphorus\stepcounter{numtrue}\fi%
    \ifoxygen    \stepcounter{numtrue}\fi%
    \ifnitrogen  \stepcounter{numtrue}\fi%
    % build sentence
    Colour code:\ %
    \ifmetalion\textcolor{violet}{metal ion}\chooseDelimiter\fi%
    \ifresidue\textcolor{Green3}{residue}\chooseDelimiter\fi%
    \ifligand\textcolor{teal}{ligand}\chooseDelimiter\fi%
    \ifsubstrate\textcolor{Yellow3}{substrate}\chooseDelimiter\fi%
    \ifphosphorus\textcolor{DarkOrange1}{phosphorus}\chooseDelimiter\fi%
    \ifoxygen\textcolor{red}{oxygen}\chooseDelimiter\fi%
    \ifnitrogen\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{nitrogen}\chooseDelimiter\fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Works with one atom:}
    \ColourGuide[metalion]
    
    \paragraph{Works with two atoms:}
    \noindent\ColourGuide[residue,ligand]\\ % two atoms
    
    \paragraph{Works with many atoms:}
    \ColourGuide[metalion,residue,ligand,substrate,phosphorus,oxygen,nitrogen]\\ % many atoms
    
    \paragraph{Keeps the given order, no matter what is the order in brackets:}
    \ColourGuide[ligand, residue]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I welcome all types of answers, this could be helpful to someone in the future using `tikz/pgf`, thanks a lot :)